# could not read symbols: File truncated

Tags: gcc, hyperlink, g++

arm-elf-g++ link static lib *.a failed：

libreData.a: could not read symbols: File truncated

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

gnu_make: *** [partial.obj] Error 1

I tried to use the "-mlong-calls" compile option to fix the question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and how to provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The lib compile add the option "-mlong-calls" lead relocation flag "R_ARM_MOVW_ABS_NC".
Not add the option "-mlong-calls" lead relocation flag "R_ARM_PC24".